# Numerical integration of iterated integral with piecewise integrand

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, piecewise

I need to plot the following integral:
$$
\Omega(t)=\int^{x_1(t)}_0 {4\pi x_i^2\rho(x_i,t=t_s)\int^\infty_04\pi x^2\rho_{reg}(x_i,x,t)dx}dx_i
$$

where

$$
    \rho(x_i,t)=
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\text{$\omega_0$}(t)^2 \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(-\frac{\text{$x_0$} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};-4 \text{$x_i$}^4 \text{$\xi_0 $}^2 \text{$\omega_0$}(t)^2\right)-\text{$x_i$} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};-4 \text{$x_0$}^4 \text{$\xi_0 $}^2 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2\right)}{\text{$x_0$} \text{$x_i$}}-\frac{1}{\text{$x_0$}}+\frac{1}{\text{$x_i$}}\right)\right)}{8 \pi  \text{$r_c$}^3 \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}+\text{$x_0$}^4 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2} \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}+\text{$x_i$}^4 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2}},\text{$x_i$}<\text{$x_0$}\\
    \frac{\text{$\omega_0$}(t)^2 \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(\frac{\text{$x_0$} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};-4 \text{$x_i$}^4 \text{$\xi_0 $}^2 \text{$\omega_0$}(t)^2\right)-\text{$x_i$} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};-4 \text{$x_0$}^4 \text{$\xi_0 $}^2 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2\right)}{\text{$x_0$} \text{$x_i$}}-\frac{1}{\text{$x_0$}}+\frac{1}{\text{$x_i$}}\right)\right)}{8 \pi  \text{$r_c$}^3 \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}+\text{$x_0$}^4 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2} \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}+\text{$x_i$}^4 \text{$\omega_0 $}(t)^2}},\text{$x_i$}\ge\text{$x_0$}
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \\
    \rho_{reg}(x_i,x,t)=
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    \xi\beta_1(x_i,t),x<\text{$x_i$}\\
    \exp \left(\frac{1}{\xi  x}\right)\beta_2(x_i,t) +\xi\beta_3(x_i,t),\text{$x_i$}\leq x\leq \text{$x_1$}(t)\\
    \frac{\text{$\beta_4$}(\text{$x_i$},t) \exp \left(\frac{1}{2 \xi  x}-x \omega (t)\right)}{x},x>\text{$x_1$}(t)
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
$$
Here is my code:

```
sol2 = Solve[{\[Beta]2*
      Exp[
        1/(xi*\[Xi])]/\[Xi] + \[Beta]3 == \[Beta]1, \[Beta]2 == \
(\[Xi]*(\[Omega][t]^2)*Exp[-1/(xi*\[Xi])])/(4*Pi*(rc^3)), \[Beta]2*
      Exp[1/(\[Xi]*x1[t])] + \[Beta]3*\[Xi] == \[Beta]4*
     Exp[-\[Omega][t]*x1[t] + (1/(2*x1[t]*\[Xi]))]/
      x1[
       t], \[Beta]2*(Exp[
        1/(\[Xi]*x1[t])]/(\[Xi]*(x1[t]^2))) == \[Beta]4*
     Exp[-\[Omega][t]*x1[t] + 
       1/(2*\[Xi]*x1[t])]*((\[Omega][t]/
         x1[t]) + (1/(2*\[Xi]*x1[t]^3)) + (1/
         x1[t]^2))}, {\[Beta]1, \[Beta]2, \[Beta]3, \[Beta]4}]
fi1[xi_, t_] := \[Beta]1 /. sol2[[1]]
fi2[xi_, t_] := \[Beta]2 /. sol2[[1]]
fi3[xi_, t_] := \[Beta]3 /. sol2[[1]]
fi4[xi_, t_] := \[Beta]4 /. sol2[[1]]
    
x0 = 3/10
e = \
(160217663/100000000)*(10^(-19))
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 15
\[CurlyEpsilon]0 = (8854/1000)*(10^(-12))
k = ((1380649/1000000)*(10^(-23)))/
  e
T = 111
rc = (e/(4*Pi*\[CurlyEpsilon]*\[CurlyEpsilon]0*k*
     T))
E0 = 0.2
\[Alpha] = (k*T)/E0
\[Gamma] = (4/3)*(10^(9))
Nt = (10^(27))/((15/10)^3)
a = (15/10)*(10^(-9))
\[Nu]0 = 10^(13)
Etr = 3*E0*
  Log[((Pi*Nt/(\[Gamma]^3))^(1/
        3))/\[Alpha]]
Dc = \[Nu]0*(((87/
        100)*(Nt^(-1/3)))^2)*Exp[-(174/100)*\[Gamma]*(Nt^(-1/3))]
\[Tau]\[Omicron] = 10^(-12)
ts = 
 Exp[232/(100*\[Alpha])]
\[Tau][
  t_] := \[Tau]\[Omicron]*
  Exp[Etr/E0]*(t^(\[Alpha]))(*при t>ts,E(t)=kT*)
\[Tau]0[
  t_] := ((Log[t])^2)/(24*(\[Gamma]^2)*
    Dc)
\[Xi] = 1
\[Xi]0 = 1/\[Alpha]
\[Omega][t_] := rc/Sqrt[Dc*\[Tau][t]]
\[Omega]0[t_] := rc/Sqrt[Dc*\[Tau]0[t]]
x1[t_] := ((Dc*\[Tau][t])/(4*(\[Xi]^2)*(rc^2)))^(1/
    4)

x10[t_] := ((Dc*\[Tau]0[t])/(4*(\[Xi]0^2)*(rc^2)))^(1/4)
    
    \[Rho][xi_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*
       Exp[(\[Alpha]/
           2)*((1/xi) - (1/
             x0) - ((x0*
                Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, -1/4, 
                 3/4, -4*(xi^4)*(\[Xi]0^2)*((\[Omega]0[t])^2)] - 
               xi*
                Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, -1/4, 
                 3/4, -4*(x0^4)*(\[Xi]0^2)*((\[Omega]0[t])^2)])/(xi*
               x0)))])/(8*
       Pi*(rc^3)*((((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*(xi^4) + ((\[Alpha]^2)/4))^(1/
           4))*((((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*(x0^4) + ((\[Alpha]^2)/4))^(1/
           4))), 
    xi < 
     x0}, {(((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*
       Exp[(\[Alpha]/
           2)*((1/xi) - (1/
             x0) + ((x0*
                Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, -1/4, 
                 3/4, -4*(xi^4)*(\[Xi]0^2)*((\[Omega]0[t])^2)] - 
               xi*
                Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, -1/4, 
                 3/4, -4*(x0^4)*(\[Xi]0^2)*((\[Omega]0[t])^2)])/(xi*
               x0)))])/(8*
       Pi*(rc^3)*((((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*(xi^4) + ((\[Alpha]^2)/4))^(1/
           4))*((((\[Omega]0[t])^2)*(x0^4) + ((\[Alpha]^2)/4))^(1/
           4))), xi >= x0}}]
    \[Rho]reg[x_, xi_, t_] := (x^2)*
  Piecewise[{{fi1[xi, t]*\[Xi], 
     x < xi}, {fi2[xi, t]*Exp[1/(x*\[Xi])] + fi3[xi, t]*\[Xi], 
     xi <= x <= x1[t]}, {fi4[xi, t]*
      Exp[-\[Omega][t]*x + (1/(2*x*\[Xi]))]/x, x > x1[t]}}]

int4[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  4*Pi*(rc^3)*(xi^2)*\[Rho][xi, ts]*4*
   Pi*(rc^3)*\[Rho]reg[x, xi, t], {xi, 0, x1[t]}, {x, 0, Infinity}]
    
LogLogPlot[int4[t], {t, 1, 10^50}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10^50}, {10^(-6), 1}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Nu]0*t", ""}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\)]\)=0.3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(r\), \(c\)]\) T=111K \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)=0.2эВ \
\[CurlyEpsilon]=15 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \
\(0\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-12\)]\)с"]
```

The result is:

[image]

with this error:

[image]

While I expected something like this:

[image]

I checked my parameters. Everything seems to be correct. So, I assume that the problem is in my implementation of NIntegrate. How to numerically integrate such functions correctly?

Comment: If you copy your `sol2` into a notebook, you will see that the brackets don't match, there is a superfluous backslash. Once that is done, please try calling `fi1[7,13]`. I believe you expect the numbers `7` and `13` to appear in the result, but they do not, in fact the symbols `xi` and `t` are still there! Then try `fi1[xx_,tt_]:=Block[{xi=xx,t=tt},\[Beta]1/. sol2[[1]]]`.

Comment: @user293787 I apologize for the inconvenience. I edited my code and tried what you suggested. It gave me the same results but without errors.